# XML Serialization in visual studio

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, mstest

im trying to use displayname in my xml test and for some reazone the test dosent conect to the xml (it was conected and then i did somthing and its not conected any more)
please help me, i am a student and i need to submit my project to day
my xml convert to cs:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClockD
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "IsEarlier")]
    public class IsEarlier
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "hour1")]
        public string Hour1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "min1")]
        public string Min1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "hour2")]
        public string Hour2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "min2")]
        public string Min2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "res")]
        public string Res { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DisplayName")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "tar")]
    public class Tar
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsEarlier")]
        public List<IsEarlier> IsEarlier { get; set; }
    }

}
```

my tests:

```
using ClockD;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace ClockDUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class IsEarlierTest
    {
        private TestContext context;
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return context; }
            set { context = value; }
        }


        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
            @"|DataDirectory|\ClockD\IsEarlier.cs",
            "IsEarlier",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        public void IsEarlierByXML()
        {
            int h1 = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["hour1"].ToString());
            int m1 = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["min1"].ToString());
            ClockD.Clock c1 = new ClockD.Clock(h1, m1);

            int h2 = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["hour2"].ToString());
            int m2 = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["min2"].ToString());
            ClockD.Clock c2 = new ClockD.Clock(h2, m2);


            bool expected = Convert.ToBoolean(TestContext.DataRow["res"].ToString());
            bool actual;

            actual = c1.IsEarlier(c2);

            Assert.IsTrue(expected == actual);
        }
    }
}
```

i need to use displayName in xml test (like we use in DataRow)

Comment: You did not specify the xml file in the DataSource attribute, but the cs file.

Comment: What changed since code was working?  Open XML with Notepad and see if XML looks correct.